# SSL SYSCALL error: Bad file descriptor on Heroku with postgres and Celery

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, celery

I've been using Celery successfully with a Django site on Heroku but it's just started generating the error below, which stops it running. It looks like it's having trouble with postgres, but I'm stumped as to how to fix it, given it's Celery rather than my code that's having the problem (I assume...).

I'm using CloudAMPQ as a broker, and my Django settings include:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Here's the traceback from the Heroku logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 323, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'scheduler'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: Bad file descriptor


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/billiard/process.py", line 292, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 553, in run
    self.service.start(embedded_process=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 470, in start
    humanize_seconds(self.scheduler.max_interval))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 325, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 512, in scheduler
    return self.get_scheduler()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 507, in get_scheduler
    lazy=lazy)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 53, in instantiate
    return symbol_by_name(name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djcelery/schedulers.py", line 151, in __init__
    Scheduler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.setup_schedule()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djcelery/schedulers.py", line 158, in setup_schedule
    self.install_default_entries(self.schedule)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djcelery/schedulers.py", line 251, in schedule
    self._schedule = self.all_as_schedule()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djcelery/schedulers.py", line 164, in all_as_schedule
    for model in self.Model.objects.enabled():
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: SSL SYSCALL error: Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue now... there was a line of my Django code which had caused an Internal Server Error in the past -- I think, early on in Django starting up, it was trying to access a model before the migrations that created the model had run.

I'd resolved that but noticed these "SSL SYSCALL error"s started about the same time. So I removed that line of code, and Celery has started up again.

It could be coincidence. And I don't understand why this fixed things.

Ideally I'd still like to understand what the error above actually *means* so I'd have a better chance of fixing such a thing in the future.

Comment: What was that line you talk about? what made the difference?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I think it was something quite specific to my code, for a client, that I either couldn't share or wasn't useful on its own. Sorry I can't be more help - I never worked out if that was in fact the solution or just a coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and i solved.
In my case the problem was a custom AppConfig in one of my django apps.

my folder

```
my_django_app/
  __init__.py
  apps.py
  ...
```

I have a file `my_django_app/__init__.py` like this

```py
default_app_config="my_django_app.apps.MyAppConfig"
```

and the file `my_django_app/apps.py` like this

```py
class ChallengeConfig(AppConfig):
    
    name = 'appConfig'
    verbose_name = "djangoAppConfig"

    def ready(self):
        ... # custom logic
```

After removeing the line `default_app_config="my_django_app.apps.MyAppConfig"` celery works again

If you have something like this, remove your custom AppConfig and use a celery periodic task instead of a custom AppConfig. django_celery_beat do something strange with AppConfig so if you have a custom AppConfig it generate the problem

My python requirements:

```
Django==1.11.29
celery==4.4.7
django_celery_beat==1.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked years ago, but this was about the only question out there which related to my problem.

In my case, it was down to the CONN_MAX_AGE being set at 600. Reduced to 0 so that there are unlimited persistent connections.

From the docs:

> Persistent connections avoid the overhead of re-establishing a connection to the database in each request. They’re controlled by the CONN_MAX_AGE parameter which defines the maximum lifetime of a connection. It can be set independently for each database.

> The default value is 0, preserving the historical behavior of closing the database connection at the end of each request. To enable persistent connections, set CONN_MAX_AGE to a positive integer of seconds. For unlimited persistent connections, set it to None.

> Django opens a connection to the database when it first makes a database query. It keeps this connection open and reuses it in subsequent requests. Django closes the connection once it exceeds the maximum age defined by CONN_MAX_AGE or when it isn’t usable any longer.

> In detail, Django automatically opens a connection to the database whenever it needs one and doesn’t have one already — either because this is the first connection, or because the previous connection was closed.

> At the beginning of each request, Django closes the connection if it has reached its maximum age. If your database terminates idle connections after some time, you should set CONN_MAX_AGE to a lower value, so that Django doesn’t attempt to use a connection that has been terminated by the database server. (This problem may only affect very low traffic sites.)

> At the end of each request, Django closes the connection if it has reached its maximum age or if it is in an unrecoverable error state. If any database errors have occurred while processing the requests, Django checks whether the connection still works, and closes it if it doesn’t. Thus, database errors affect at most one request; if the connection becomes unusable, the next request gets a fresh connection.